# Form Event OnSave not executing Promise

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, webresource

I have a web resource in Dynamics CRM where I am trying to add logic to execute on save.  I am using the `addOnSave()` method to attach my logic to the save.  When I use a Promise in my save logic, Save & Close exits the page before my save completes.  How can I get my save logic to fully execute before the web resource is closed?

### pseudocode

```
Xrm.Event.addOnSave(function () {
  // Code makes it here
  Promise.all([promises]).then(function(){
    // Code never makes it here
    secondPromise.then(function(){
      showAlert();
      setTimeout(function(){
        closeAlert();
      }, 5000);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to cancel the save and then reissue it, like this:

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.addOnSave(function (context) {
  var eventArgs = context.getEventArgs();
  eventArgs.preventDefault(); // cancels the save (but other save handlers will still run)

  Promise.all([promises]).then(function(){
    // Code never makes it here
    secondPromise.then(function(){
      showAlert();
      setTimeout(function(){
        closeAlert();

        // reissue the save
        Xrm.Page.data.entity.save('saveandclose');
      }, 5000);
    });
  });
});
```

In response to your comment about the bug where preventDefault doesn't properly stop a Save and Close event: use the Ribbon Workbench from the XrmToolbox to override the Save and Close button to point to a custom function which might look something like this:

```
function customSaveAndClose() {
  if (customSaveIsNeeded) {
    // execute your custom code
  } else {
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.save('saveandclose');
  }
}
```

You can for sure override the S&C button at the Application Ribbon level which would override it for all entities, but I believe you can override it for just one entity at a time as well.

If you don't want to mess with editing the ribbon (it's a little intimidating if you've never done it before) and if you don't have strict requirements regarding unsupported customizations, you can also take the easier route of simply overriding the Mscrm.RibbonActions.saveAndCloseForm function which is what the native S&C buttons call.  That would look something like this:

```
// defined in /_static/_common/scripts/RibbonActions.js
Mscrm.RibbonActions.saveAndCloseForm = function() {
   // your code here
}
```

Some things to note about this approach:

- It's not supported and could break with any update
- CRM forms consist of multiple frames, so if you define that function in your custom script and it doesn't get executed, change your definition to `top.Mscrm` instead of just `Mscrm`.
- If you have to support mobile clients, you should probably avoid this approach and override the ribbon button instead.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  The original save & close is never prevented.  I tested this by putting the prevent code in and then never reissuing the save, but the screen still closes out and saves.

Comment: A little more research shows that this will prevent the save but does not prevent the close.  I end up with the same issue of the form exiting before my custom save of the web resource completes.

Comment: For the time being, we have removed the Save & Close button so that a user must navigate away from the page after a save.  We also added a pop up box to train the user to wait for the save to complete before navigating away.  At some point we may come back and customize a button to do the Save & Close.