# How can I work with save and route button Dynamics 365?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, save, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I need to validate if some notes exist in Dynamics 365 before saving and assign (route), the problem is that fetch goes async and save goes sync... I know that by now Microsft recommends going async, so what's the viable solution to do? Save can be canceled and called, but how can I cancel and call the button save and route? or something similar to do this async?

I have tried a lot of similar things, but it doesn't work.

**Is there some AddChange to Notes(linked to Entity)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically we will cancel the **Save** event using `preventDefault()`, complete the required steps & reissue the **Save** like [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45947799).

In your scenario, special `Save & Route` button is achieving Save as well as **Apply Routing Rule** action. There’s no save mode for this sequence to use `getSaveMode` for intercepting & reissue. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/save-event-arguments/getsavemode)

But you can try a custom **Save & Route** button using Ribbon workbench and invoke a custom Javascript action to do:

1. Validate your **Notes** record check using fetchXML/web api
2. Save the record
3. Call the `ApplyRoutingRule` action using webapi [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/applyroutingrule?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)

Don’t forget that `Xrm.WebApi` is always Asynchronous, you have to do chain of calls inside success callback or use `XMLHttpRequest` for synchronous mode. [Read more](https://arundynamix.blogspot.com/2018/10/xrmwebapi-call-synchronous-in-v9.html)

**Update**: I composed this snippet with the help of CRM REST Builder, try it.

```
var parameters = {};
var target = {};
target.incidentid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"; 
target["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.incident";
parameters.Target = target;

var applyRoutingRuleRequest = {
    Target: parameters.Target,

    getMetadata: function() {
        return {
            boundParameter: null,
            parameterTypes: {
                "Target": {
                    "typeName": "mscrm.crmbaseentity",
                    "structuralProperty": 5
                }
            },
            operationType: 0,
            operationName: "ApplyRoutingRule"
        };
    }
};

Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(applyRoutingRuleRequest).then(
    function success(result) {
        if (result.ok) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try

Comment: Is some sample of ApplyRoutingRole? or u know how it works? can I specified the applyroutingRole? Thanks again for the help... doc about this is little bit

Comment: thanks you for the active help, I really appreciate. It seems to  works... but with the native button after execution it redirect to another page, and with the custom button it doesn't... is this by some parameter off or something? Thanks again...

Comment: @danielmontecinos: you can land in any page at the end of the execution if (result.ok) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openform if my answer helped you - upvote/accept it so this will help others too